# AttributeError: 'TensorShape' object has no attribute 'assert_has_rank' (when trying to predict on an image classification keras model)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I took over a simple convolutional network from the internet for a simple binary image classification task, it's my first try on image classification. It trains well on the sets of images I collected. This is the code for training:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D , MaxPool2D , Flatten , Dropout 
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

cwd = os.getcwd()

my_file = Path(cwd + "/ddornotbiclassifier/keras_model.h5")

labels = ['dd', 'notadd']
img_size = 224
def get_data(data_dir):
    data = [] 
    for label in labels: 
        path = os.path.join(data_dir, label)
        class_num = labels.index(label)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_arr = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img))[...,::-1] #convert BGR to RGB format
                resized_arr = cv2.resize(img_arr, (img_size, img_size)) # Reshaping images to preferred size
                data.append([resized_arr, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    return np.array(data)

train = get_data(cwd + "/images/dd_notadd/train")
val = get_data(cwd + "/images/dd_notadd/valid")

l = []
for i in train:
    if(i[1] == 0):
        l.append("dd")
    else:
        l.append("notdd")
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
sns.countplot(l)

x_train = []
y_train = []
x_val = []
y_val = []

for feature, label in train:
  x_train.append(feature)
  y_train.append(label)

for feature, label in val:
  x_val.append(feature)
  y_val.append(label)

# Normalize the data
x_train = np.array(x_train) / 255
x_val = np.array(x_val) / 255

x_train.reshape(-1, img_size, img_size, 1)
y_train = np.array(y_train)

x_val.reshape(-1, img_size, img_size, 1)
y_val = np.array(y_val)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
        samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
        zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
        rotation_range = 30,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        zoom_range = 0.2, # Randomly zoom image 
        width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        horizontal_flip = True,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=False)  # randomly flip images


datagen.fit(x_train)

if not my_file.is_file():
    print("There was no saved model so model will be trained from scratch")
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32,3,padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=(224,224,3)))
    model.add(MaxPool2D())
    
    model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(MaxPool2D())
    
    model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(MaxPool2D())
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128,activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))
    
    model.summary()
    
    opt = Adam(lr=0.000001)
    model.compile(optimizer = opt , loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True) , metrics = ['accuracy'])
else:
    print("There was a saved model so that model will be loaded and continued to train")
    pathtomodel = cwd + '/ddornotbiclassifier/keras_model.h5'
    model = keras.models.load_model(pathtomodel)
    
    opt = Adam(lr=0.000001)
    model.compile(optimizer = opt , loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True) , metrics = ['accuracy'])    

history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs = 3085, validation_data = (x_val, y_val))

acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs_range = range(3085)

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.show()

predictions = model.predict_classes(x_val)
predictions = predictions.reshape(1,-1)[0]
print(classification_report(y_val, predictions, target_names = ['dd (Class 0)','notadd (Class 1)']))

model.save("./ddornotbiclassifier/keras_model.h5")
```

Then I created another python file to predict on the model. This is what I have so far:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D , MaxPool2D , Flatten , Dropout 
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

cwd = os.getcwd()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,3,padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=(224,224,3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))

pathtomodel = cwd + '/ddornotbiclassifier/keras_model.h5'

model.load_weights(pathtomodel)
    
opt = Adam(lr=0.000001)
model.compile(optimizer = opt , loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True) , metrics = ['accuracy'])

path = cwd + "/images/dd_notadd/testimage/testimage.jpeg"
img = cv2.imread(path)
img = cv2.resize(img,(224,224))
img = np.reshape(img,[1,224,224,3])

model.predict(img)
```

Then this is the output:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:9 out of the last 11 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x7fe6e5799430> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/lennartkonst/Documents/Chatbots/Pythonbots/DreamDestinationsBot/ML/ddornotinference2.py", line 44, in <module>
    model.predict(img)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 130, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1614, in predict
    all_outputs = nest.map_structure_up_to(batch_outputs, concat, outputs)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 1135, in map_structure_up_to
    return map_structure_with_tuple_paths_up_to(

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 1234, in map_structure_with_tuple_paths_up_to
    results = [func(*args, **kwargs) for args in zip(flat_path_list,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 1234, in <listcomp>
    results = [func(*args, **kwargs) for args in zip(flat_path_list,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 1137, in <lambda>
    lambda _, *values: func(*values),  # Discards the path arg.

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2673, in concat
    return array_ops.concat(tensors, axis=axis)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1650, in concat
    ops.convert_to_tensor(

AttributeError: 'TensorShape' object has no attribute 'assert_has_rank'
```

I'm stuck and it gives this error on many type of tries. A numpy array of shape 1,224,224,3 should do it right?

What should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you try removing `from_logits=True` in the loss function? Also what version of Tensorflow are you using?

Comment: Removing ```from_logits=True``` does not remove the error. 2.3.1. Thanks!